# MSMQ on windows server 2008

Tags: msmq, msmq-wcf

I installed MSMQ on windows server 2008 in workgroup mode. I noticed there is only a private queue and a public queue is missing.
It causes I can't send message from remote computers. I see the messages in outgoing queues. the state is "Waiting to connect" and the Connection History is "No failures reported".

I have two questions:

1. Can I add the public queue option in any way?
2. What should I do in order to enable sending message to private queue in remote computer?

(I use WCF.)

Thanks in advane!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my job we also meet that issue.

The solution was opening the ports that msmq is working with:

**TCP: 1801
RPC: 135, 2101*, 2103*, 2105*
UDP: 3527, 1801**

Good Luck.

Comment: So you are basically hacking the box to remotely connect into a private queue?  That is the best answer?